# jquery select first td of a tr in a table, then iterate through the findings and compare text with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having a table like:

```
<table id="table_1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the first td of each table row. 
Then i want to iterate through the findings and compare the text value contained in the td with a value i have.

So far, i can get the first td of each tr by using the following :

```
var test = $("#table_1").find('td:first-child');
```

Then i get the number of tds : `console.log(test.length);`
but when i try to get the text of a td i get an error : `console.log(test[1].text());`
Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: test[1].text is not a function
```

Obviously i do something wrong. Is my way of thinking wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: This is not what i want, as it returns the concatenation of the texts of the tds. I want to get each value separately and dynamically. Lets say if i have 10 tds i want the value of each one to compare it with a variable i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test[1]` will return underlying DOM element and `.text()` is a jQuery function thus you are getting the error.

I think, You need to use `.eq()`

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

*Code*

```
test.eq(0).text()
```

Note: that the supplied index is zero-based, and refers to the position of the element within the jQuery object, not within the DOM tree.

*OR*, Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
test[1].textContent
```

Answer (score 2):

`test` is jquery object of all first child elements. You should be using `.eq(0)` or `.first()` to target first element in the collection:

```
 console.log(test.eq(0).text());
```

or

```
 console.log(test.first().text());
```

**Update:** To get all the texts of first-child td elements in array

```
 var allfirsttdtext = test.map(function(){
     return $(this).text();
 }).get();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d4qp12b4/)**

Comment: If i have 50 of them how am i going to get each value separately?

Answer (score 0):

use **textContent** in JavaScript  bcoz u are converting jquery object into javascript object

```
console.log(test.eq(0).text());
```

or 
    `console.log(test[0].textContent);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround by jQuery as the resulted array is a Dom Elements:

```
for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  console.log($(test[i]).text())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var v = 'compare';

 $('#table_1 td').each(function () {
       if ($(this).text() == v)
       console.log($(this).text()+' is equal with the variable '+v);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(test[1].text());
```

test -> is an array of htmlDomElement
when you say `test[1] ->` it gives you a htmlElement not a jQuery object of that element, so you can not use `.text()` which is jQuery function.

Wrap it with `$(test[1]).text()` to make it jQuery object to use `text()` function on it.